# Code Exceeds JS Function Boundaries and Fires Instantly

Tags: leaflet, mapquest

The following code is in a javascript function within a file called maplocation.js that is supposed to fire only on a button click but instead it fires automatically when the page loads for the first time. The code does not wait for the button click but loads the map instantly. On button click it is supposed to add a new image of a car to the location.

```
window.map.panTo([data.Data.LatLng.Lat, data.Data.LatLng.Lng]);

                        var vehicleIcon = L.icon({
                            iconUrl: settings.mapIcon,
                            iconSize: [22, 25],
                            iconAnchor: [11, 20],
                            popupAnchor: [0, -22]
                        });

                        L.circle([data.Data.LatLng.Lat, data.Data.LatLng.Lng], 140, { color: 'Green' }).addTo(window.map);

                        L.marker([data.Data.LatLng.Lat, data.Data.LatLng.Lng], { icon: vehicleIcon }).addTo(window.map).bindPopup("<b style='width:200px;'>" + settings.mapTitle + "</b><br />");
```

Comment: Nothing in your code would make it react on a button ...

Comment: What happens is there is an OnClientClick mentod set in ASP.NET WebForms with the parameters being set for the button's click event. So this code above is part of the function called MapLocation.js which gets loaded via script tags. To be  clear, on application load my first JS file loads a map to locate a phone's lat long. But the MapLocation.js file loads afterwards. Somehow, although the code above is in a function called MapLocation, it fires during the page load cycle. So, the map that loaded first gets overwritten immediately after the first map loads